# Spring Boot 1.3.8 @Profile and properties

Tags: spring-boot, profile, application.properties

I do use profiles in my Spring Boot application. In my application.properties I have this 3 entries:

```
spring.profiles.active=prod
key1=demo. ...
key1=prod. ...
```

Currently I have to uncomment the line depending on whether it is a demo or a productive release.
Is there a better way of doing this using profiles of Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create property files with postfix of your profile name and dump profile specific properties there.

For example,

in your `application-prod.properties` this one will go `key1=prod. ...`
in your `application-demo.properties` this one will go `key1=demo. ...`

And while starting the server pass this java param `-Dspring.profiles.active=<profilename>` or set env variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=<profile_name>`

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be achieved:

1. Use a single application.properties and having values in following format:

   ```
   redis.host=${REDIS_HOST}
   redis.port=${REDIS_PORT}
   ```
2. Now use different .yml files for dev, staging and prod environments, where each file has values related to specific environment. For example, dev.yml, staging.yml, prod.yml:

   ```
   // dev.yml
   REDIS_HOST=localhost
   REDIS_PORT=6379

   // staging.yml
   REDIS_HOST=staging-url
   REDIS_PORT=6576

   //prod.yml
   REDIS_HOST=produrl
   REDIS_PORT=5678
   ```
3. Now, run the application with profile parameter being passed for different environments:

   ```
   -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
   ```

Comment: I also use spring boot 1.2.3 and it does not work with -Dspring.profiles.active=dev. Actually i dont know.